# How do I collapse list #1 when I select a <li> from list #2 or list #3?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I am trying to collapse < ul class="list1" > when I select a < li > from list 2 (< ul class="list2" >) or from list 3 (< ul class="list3" >)

Currently, if I open a list, it remains open and does not close the other lists that are already open.

HTML:

```
<ul class="components">

<!-- LIST 1 -->
  <li>
    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
      Home
    </a>
    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="list1">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Inicio 1</a>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href="#">Inicio 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Inicio 3</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
   </li>

<!-- LIST 2 -->
   <li>
    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
      Second home
    </a>
    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="list2">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Inicio 1</a>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href="#">Inicio 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Inicio 3</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
   </li>

<!-- LIST 3 -->
   < li >
    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
      Another Home
    </a>
    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="list3">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Inicio 1</a>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href="#">Inicio 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Inicio 3</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
 $('.components li a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.closest('ul').children('li').removeClass('active');
   $this.parent().addClass('active');
 });
});
```

The result is that all items < li > selected remain and no list collapses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.components li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var mainList = $this.closest('ul');
    var subLists = mainList.children('li').children('ul');

    mainList.children('li').removeClass('active');
    subLists.addClass('collapse');

    $this.parent().addClass('active');
    var selectedSublist = $this.closest('li').children('ul')
    if (selectedSublist.hasClass('collapse'))
      selectedSublist.removeClass('collapse');
    else
      selectedSublist.addClass('collapse');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="components">
  <!-- LIST 1 -->
  <li>
    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
      Home
    </a>

    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="list1">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Inicio 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Inicio 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Inicio 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <!-- LIST 2 -->
  <li>
    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
      Second home
    </a>
    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="list2">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Inicio 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Inicio 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Inicio 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <!-- LIST 3 -->
  <li>
    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
      Another Home
    </a>
    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="list3">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Inicio 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Inicio 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Inicio 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The <ul> closes correctly but does not make any animation.

Before it did the collapse animation of Bootstrap and now it only closes abruptly when changing the library to which it points.

Do you know how I can fix this?